# Python replace the default __str__ implementation of datetime?

Tags: python

Is it a way to replace/customize the default `__str__` of datetime?

```
from datetime import datetime
x = datetime.now() # x can be any date from parameters
print(x) # str(x) returns 2020-10-07 10:38:08.048291 too, but I want a different format
```

I need to change the default `__str__` behave for other functions like `json.dump(x, default=str)`.

```
x = 12, 'abc', datetime.now(), 223, ....
json.dump(x, default=str)
```

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime

Comment: Any reason not to use [strftime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)?

Comment: I've updated the question. The purpose is for the call of `json.dump(x, default=str)`

Comment: Doesn't change the fact that you can use `strftime`... `json.dump((12, 'abc', datetime.now().strftime("your/format")))`

Comment: @ca9163d9 I think I found a good un-intrusive [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64247039/941531) for json conversion case instead of modifying `datetime` `__str__` method.

Answer (score 1):

I think next is a cleaner un-intrusive approach for your case rather than modifying `datetime` class's `__str__` method. You provide custom convertors for any types you need like `datetime`, while the rest is tried to be converted to json if not possible then falling back to using `str(x)` if it is json-unconvertable type (like numpy array in my example).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZBNa8MwDIbv/hW@hDhgAlv3AYbdd9lpxxCKlzjUpZGNrWwJY789k9M07WA6WXpe6ZXsJzw42M2z7b0LyI/RAeuC63mr0aDtDV/JJWdrDkPvJ64jB8@Y@zjyF/7NOEWeVLnaGkpwX6KQZ@bwYALB6k7ey129ViOGfePgkwD4UoegJ1FVD/KxltWTfK5rav9hrDXdsuCeHno4oRgLtQywHbfRQkQNjRGj3LxXniIYHALwsSSzLjGRZ68qe1PZe14sKnOK5qrHMF2TFMm5bOnqSL5/yGX0VjRjYzyq/0TkntqZDxZQ3MykL6S9z4fRX97eWRRsnn8B)

```
import json
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np

obj = {
    'time': datetime.now(),
    'other': [1,2,3],
    'str_conv': np.array([[4,5],[6,7]]),
}

def json_default(x):
    if isinstance(x, datetime):
        return x.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    else:
        try:
            json.dumps(x)
            return x
        except:
            return str(x)

print(json.dumps(obj, default = json_default))
```

output

```
{"time": "18:24:57", "other": [1, 2, 3], "str_conv": "[[4 5]\n [6 7]]"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the output format using strftime(). It's described [here](https://pymotw.com/3/datetime/) under "Formatting and parsing".